# No transaction started in current thread error

Tags: java, lucene, xodus

I have this code that needs to index a document:

```java
  @Override public Boolean index(String dir, String entityId, Double longitude, Double latitude)
      throws Exception {
    if (writer == null) {
      writer = DatabaseManagerImpl.getInstance().getIndexWriter(dir);
    }
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new StoredField("entityId", entityId));
    doc.add(new LatLonPoint("latlon", latitude, longitude));
    Geo3DPoint point = new Geo3DPoint("geo3d", latitude, longitude);
    doc.add(point);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    return null;
  }
```

With this index writer configuration:

```java
  public IndexWriter getIndexWriter(String dir) {
    ContextualEnvironment env = Environments.newContextualInstance(dir);
    ExodusDirectory exodusDirectory = new ExodusDirectory(env, VfsConfig.DEFAULT, StoreConfig.WITHOUT_DUPLICATES_WITH_PREFIXING, new ExodusDirectoryConfig());
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
    IndexWriter writer = env.computeInTransaction(txn -> {
      try {
        return new IndexWriter(exodusDirectory, iwc);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
      }
    });
    return writer;
  }
```

And used as such:

```java
  public void testSearch() throws Exception {
    String environment = TestEnvironment.getEnvironment();
    LuceneIndexer luceneIndexer = LuceneIndexerImpl.getInstance();
    luceneIndexer.index(environment, "0-1", lon, lat);
    List<String> results = luceneIndexer.searchNeighbor(environment, lon, lat,
        10.0, null, 10);
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("0-1"));
  }
```

It throws:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction started in current
> thread
>
> at
> jetbrains.exodus.env.ContextualEnvironmentImpl.getAndCheckCurrentTransaction(ContextualEnvironmentImpl.java:51)
> at
> jetbrains.exodus.lucene.ExodusIndexOutput.(ExodusIndexOutput.kt:33)
> at
> jetbrains.exodus.lucene.ExodusDirectory.createOutput(ExodusDirectory.kt:67)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:44)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(TrackingDirectoryWrapper.java:43)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.(CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.java:112)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.fieldsWriter(CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.java:128)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.fieldsWriter(Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsConsumer.initStoredFieldsWriter(StoredFieldsConsumer.java:39)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsConsumer.startDocument(StoredFieldsConsumer.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.startStoredFields(DefaultIndexingChain.java:355)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:391)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:251)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:494)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1609)
> at
> org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1228)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xodus is a transactional database, so it requires a transaction to operate, for both reading and writing. LuceneDirectory requires a ContexualEnvironment to be created, use it to create transactions.